# The backup GPT table is corrupt

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I'm having an issue when trying to format a pen drive using Gparted. I am trying to create a bootable OS X installation, and for doing so I'm formating a usb drive with GPT and then creating 2 partitions: one with the UFI bootloader and other with the OS, but once it's gparted tells me that "The backup GPT table is corrupt" and does not read the second partition.

It doesn't matter the size it will always read the sdb1 and not the sdb2 (which I need access for copying the files).

Using GDISK I already corrected the GPT (so gparted does not issue an error) but the /dev/sdb2 is still not accessible, with its file system unrecognized.

Can you help with this?
Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

First, what tools and procedures did you use to get to the point of the "backup GPT table is corrupt" message, and is that error message reproducible by reproducing those steps? It could be that you did something wrong in creating the partitions, and that this is causing problems, but without knowing how you created the partition table and filesystems, that's impossible to know for sure.

Second, if the error is reproducible and if you're using common partitioning tools (such as Disk Utility in OS X, GParted or `gdisk` in Linux, etc.), then it's very unlikely that you'd get a consistent and reproducible problem in the partition table. This makes me think that you may have a defective USB flash drive on your hands. I can't be sure of that, though, particularly if you used some oddball tool to create the partitions.

Third, if a partition (such as `/dev/sdb2`) is inaccessible, you may need to use filesystem repair tools such as `fsck` on it. Further diagnosis would require knowledge of what filesystem it is (I'd guess HFS+, if you intend to put OS X on it). The output of `sudo fsck /dev/sdb2` and/or `sudo blkid /dev/sdb2` would be useful in further diagnosis.

Fourth, if you're trying to create a bootable OS X disk, you should probably be doing this in OS X, not in Linux. Is there some reason you're trying to use Linux for this task?

I recommend you edit your question to provide all this additional information; it's too much to fit in comments.